# Import from git on Android Studio does nothing

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, git-clone

I have a new computer and, and I want to import my current project from git.

I've just installed Android Studio and git.
I go to file -> new -> project from version control -> git. Then I've connected my github account, chose my project and clicked "clone".

At this point simply nothing happens. The dialog just closes and everything is as before. I can't find any error logs so can't quite understand what is wrong.

Comment: try to clone manually via command line from file manager and open project from android studio !

Comment: @Tsabary, **VCS>Checkout from Version Control>git** then put the `clone-url` and directory path and make sure you configured the git

Comment: nothing happens for me too

Answer (score 0):

I needed to download and install git and then it worked.

It's a bug in the android studio that they don't show a message.